# How to use Angular service in place of Ajax url property

Tags: ajax, angularjs-service, jquery-easyui

Here is code:

```
loader:function(param,success,error){
  $.ajax({
      //url: 'http://localhost/mvcController?assetid=1&dataformat=attribute',
      url: assetsMVCService.execute("mvcController", { assetId: 1, dataFormat: 'attribute' }),
      dataType: 'text',
      type: 'post',
      success: function (data) {
          alert('ok');
      },
      error: function () {
          error.apply(this, arguments);
      }
  });
```

`assetsMVCService` is my wrapper for Angular service. Unfortunately, a product that I am implementing forces me to use AJAX call to get data. Normally, I would use services to get data and then scope for data binding. Is it possible to use a service assigned to the url property in the code above? Interesting enough, I am hitting server with the code above. But something gets wrong on the server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You could do something like this:

```
app.service('MVC', function($http) {
  var root = 'http://localhost/mvcController';
  var queryParams = '?assetid=1&dataformat=attribute';

  this.get = function(num) {
    return $http.get(root + '/' + num + queryParams);
  };

  // or if you want to pass the query params in
  this.execute = function(assetId, dataFormat) {
    return $http.get(root + '?assetId=' + assetId + '&dataFormat=' + dataFormat;
  };

  // other routes
});
```

Note that [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) can and should be used instead of `$.ajax` when you're using Angular. It does pretty much the same thing as `$.ajax`, except it plays nice with Angular.